# Making `http-server` visible across the network

Tags: npm, httpserver

Running `npm`'s `http-server` will sometimes launch a server accessible from a (mobile) device on the same network.

```
> http-server
Starting up http-server, serving ./
Available on:
  http://127.0.0.1:8080
  http://10.0.1.7:8080
  http://123.456.78.90:8080
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
```

and sometimes launch a server that is visible only from the same desktop.

```
> http-server
Starting up http-server, serving ./
Available on:
  http://127.0.0.1:8080
  http://10.0.1.7:8080
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
```

How do I use `http-server` to launch a web server that's visible from any device on the same network?
The presence of `http://10.0.1.7:8080` should by itself indicate that the server is visible across the network, no?
Why does the third address `http://123.456.78.90:8080` appear only sometimes. Both launchings are identical.

All this follows `npm install -g http-server` of course.

**Update 1:**

`http-server -a 0.0.0.0` is the default. (Hence it need not be specified.)

**Update 2:**

Using

```
python3 -m http.server --bind 0.0.0.0
```

is more predictable/reliable, but then one has to go muck around in `ifconfig`'s output to find the IP revealed so nicely by `npm`'s `http-server`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should always be available to anyone in the same network as your computer under your computer's IP followed by the port.

The third address, I assume, appears because at the time you were connected to two local networks at the same time, so that the http server would be available at that IP - which is also the IP of your computer, but in the second network.

So in short:

- `http://127.0.0.1:8080` is the IP that is used to connect to the server from WITHIN the machine it runs on.
- `http://10.0.1.7:8080` and any subsequent IP is the IP used to connect to the server from any device that is in the same network. As many IP's appear as how many local networks you are connected to.

This has nothing to do with npm, it's just how the network works. Python's http server just doesn't list the IP's for you.

Comment: That makes a lot of sense. I have two routers (Airport Time Machine and Express). The presence of the third IP depends on whether the Express one is awake.

Comment: Still, something is obscure. With 3 IPs present, access from mobile device works. With only 2 IPs, there is no access, even though the first Airport is awake all the time. What am I missing?

Comment: @JohannKexel: What you wrote makes no sense, port forwarding does not apply in this situation at all.

Comment: @Calaf: What router is your phone connected to? I think you can check under the wifi settings - if it's in the range of 10.x.x.x, you should be on the same network as your PC and be able to connect.
Also, If I may ask, why do you have 2 routers at your place?

Comment: sorry, you're right. port forwarding doesn't make sense because it has nothing to do with the internet, only with internal connections. I deleted my comment.

Comment: For the love of god, why am I not a little more attentive? I was using the wrong link, this random answer helped me lol :D

Answer (score 0):

Let's try to exclude some obvious cases:

- What error message do you get? Do you see a connection timeout page in your browser?
- Is your mobile phone connected to the same router the http-server machine does?
- What is the IP of your mobile phone? (i can see it e.g. in my router)
- You don't use any vpn on your other device, do you?
- Do you see the right result when you call it locally?
- Can you ping the http-server machine from any device within your network?
- Did you try to use another port e.g 80?